# How can i use ghost4j on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, ghostscript, ghost4j

When i want to use ghost4j on OS X 10.9, i see this error:

> Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found

I have installed ghostscript library on my macbook using [this site](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/).
how can i fix this problem. I can not install ghostscript using port and brew for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to <strike>find the file `libgs.dylib` which was installed by the installer package</strike> compile the `libgs.dylib` library from source, and make a note of where you installed it to.

Hopefully it should have been installed to a standard library location, and there should be nothing more you need to do. If not, you need to set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. In a terminal this would be done by typing `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/directory`, replacing `/directory` with the full path of the actual directory containing `libgs.dylib`. After typing this, in that terminal, if you run your application, it should work. To make it take effect permanently you would need to add the `export` command to your `~/.bash_profile`. Or to make it take effect for all user accounts on your computer, you could add it to your `/etc/profile`.

If this doesn't work, I suppose the Ghostscript library could be 32-bit - you would need a 64-bit library I think.

Comment: There is not libgs.dylib file in installer package.

Comment: I meant the place where the package installed them to. See http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57579195-263/find-practically-any-file-in-os-x/

Comment: I have searched entire of my macbook hard after installation! There is not libgs.dylib file in it.

Comment: Do you know a ghostscript installer package that contain libgs.dylib?

Comment: according to http://ghostscript.com/irclogs/2012/04/30.html you have to compile it yourself (or you could use macports or brew, but you said that failed).

Comment: Is this the only way for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an old thread but maybe useful for people still looking for an answer.

Install ghostscript using [port](https://www.macports.org/)

`port install ghostscript`

That done, you need to create a link so ghost4j finds the dylib.

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.10.dylib libgs.dylib
```

Once  I did that it worked like a charm.