# Adding a dylib to the search path on OSX

Tags: java, pdf, ghostscript, ghost4j

I have a project in which I need to convert PDF file into png using ghost4j. The issue I am facing is that when I run my java code the console throws me this error:

> Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found

I googled this error and found that I also need to install ghost script and make some changes in the file `libgs.dylib`. I have installed ghost script using Mac Port but I am not able to find where this file `libgs.dylib` is located on my file system. I am clueless what to do next. Need Help.

-PS I am using Mac OS X 10.9.2 as my development environment.

Comment: Your question does not appear to be related to converting PDFs to PNGs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i use ghost4j on OS X 10.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823756/how-can-i-use-ghost4j-on-os-x-10-9?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/issues/29:

> Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH helped:
>
> ```
> $ port install ghostscript
> $ port contents ghostscript | grep libgs
>   /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.10.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libgs.dylib
> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
> ```

Use whatever path the `port contents` command reveals.

To make the changes permanent, you'll have to add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently. I don't know how to do that on OSX, as I am not a Mac user, but it is an easy thing to find out on the internet.

See also search results for ["osx install libgs.dylib"](https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+install+libgs.dylib).

Comment: I have done the steps you mentioned, but still when I run the java code I get the same error i.e "Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found". Now when I search the /opt/local/lib directory I can see the libgs.dylib file there.