# Unable to load library 'gs' with Ghost4J

Tags: java, ghostscript, ghost4j

I am trying to use Ghost4J in order to turn a PDF into a PNG. I am aware that people have asked this before, but not with OS X 10 and with the latest release of Ghost4J.

I have followed the instructions listed in zippy1978's answer from here: [PDF to image using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886042/pdf-to-image-using-java)

I have followed everything from the [Ghost4J page](http://www.ghost4j.org)

I also have tried both answers from here: [How can i use ghost4j on OS X 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823756/how-can-i-use-ghost4j-on-os-x-10-9)

And I have installed Ghostscript with [Port](https://www.macports.org) and have tried from [Richard Koch's website](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/).

I continue to get this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
    at org.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(GhostscriptLibraryLoader.java:39)
    at org.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary.<clinit>(GhostscriptLibrary.java:34)
    at org.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:323)
    at org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer.run(SimpleRenderer.java:105)
    at org.ghost4j.renderer.AbstractRemoteRenderer.render(AbstractRemoteRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ghost4j.renderer.AbstractRemoteRenderer.render(AbstractRemoteRenderer.java:70)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.controller.rest.yyyyyController.zzzz(yyyyyController.java:182)
```

What am I missing here?

The code from my Controller that is crashing is this (I marked the line):

```
// imgSrc is the PDF in Base 64 and output file is a File

byte[] imageByte;
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imgSrc);
outputfile = new File("image.pdf");
OutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
fop.write(imageByte);
fop.flush();
fop.close();
PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
document.load(outputfile);
SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
renderer.setResolution(300);
List images = renderer.render(document);       //CRASH TAKES PLACE HERE ***
outputfile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(0), "png", outputfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out!

I found the answer in this [conversation](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/issues/29):

> I had the same problem, although I had installed macports package
> "ghostscript" already. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH helped:
>
> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib

This caused a warning message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (slideselector.facedata.FaceDataParser).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Which was solved by the help of: [How to initialize log4j properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly)

> For all maven guys like me: put the log4j.properties into
> src/main/resources